# Returning data from a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file drop class. User drop images on (as many as they wish) and these are then uploaded.

I call the class via from my main class:

```
this.fileDrop = new lx.FileDrop();
```

Here's the class:

```
(function(){
"use strict";

var FileDrop = function() {
    this.init();
};

p.init = function() {

    this._initEvents();

};

p._initEvents = function() {

    $(window).on('drop', this.onDrop.bind(this)).on('dragover', this.onDragOver);

};


p.onDrop = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    $.each(files, function(index, file){


        self.readFile(file).done(function(data) {

            //how to return the data?
        });

    });

};

p.onDragOver = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};

p.readFile = function(file) {

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    fileReader.onload = function(event) {

        deferred.resolve(event.target.result);
    };

    fileReader.onerror = function() {
        deferred.reject(this);
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    return deferred.promise();

};


lx.FileDrop = FileDrop;
}(window));
```

My question concerns returning the image data to the main class. How can I return it? How can I store it - I wish to store everything that is returned into an array in the main class. How would this work when uploading multiple images. Would some sort of deferred work?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred(),
    images = [];

$.each(files, function(index, file){

    self.readFile(file).done(function(data) {

        dfd.progress(data);
        images.push(data);
        if(files.length === ++index)
            dfd.resolve(images);

    }).fail(dfd.reject);
});
```

Handle the deferred object where ever you like:

```
dfd.progress(function(file){
    console.log('file successfully uploaded', file);
}).done(function(images){
    console.log('all files successfully uploaded', images);
}).fail(function(){
    console.log('something went wrong while uploading an image');
});
```

Another example:

```
function FileDrop(){
    this.uploadCount = 0;
    this.images = [];
}

FileDrop.prototype.getImages = function(){

    var dfd = $.Deferred(),
        size = 3,
        that = this;

    for(var i = 0; i < size; i++){

        this.getImage(i*500, function(image){
            var dummyImage = $('<img/>'); 
                // should be 'image' from the callback in your case
            that.images.push(dummyImage);
            dfd.notify(dummyImage);
            if(that.uploadCount === size){
                dfd.resolve(that.images);
            }
        });
    }

    return dfd.promise();
};

FileDrop.prototype.getImage = function(timeout, callback){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        that.uploadCount++;
        callback();
    }, timeout);
};

var fd = new FileDrop();

fd.getImages().progress(function(image){
    console.log('progress', image);
}).done(function(imageArray){
    // preferred way: 
    //access the array when you know it's complete in the callback
    console.log('done', imageArray);
});

setTimeout(function(){
    // I think this is what you asked for, however, you must make an 
    // assumption when the images are completed, which is a bad idea
    console.log(fd.images);
}, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nm5vK/2/

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not sure how this would work with my master class, how can I return the image array to the master class and assign it to a var?

Comment: @panthro Declare `images` outside of your `onDrop` function. Though I suggest that you look when the deferred is `done`, rather than inspecting a variable which _might_ contain all the images you want.

Comment: Im not sure how that would work with the master class.

Comment: @panthro Can you give me an example when you want to access the images?

Comment: In my master class I have: this.fileDrop = new lx.FileDrop(); I wish to store them, something like myImgArray = new lx.FileDrop(); The file drop class should return all the images.

Comment: @panthro I'll make a jsfiddle with an example

Comment: @panthro Since you're using asynchronous calls, you want to make use of a callback to know when your images are loaded. I made an example with a timeout to simulate your readFile function: http://jsfiddle.net/Nm5vK/2/

Comment: Thanks for the example. In your example you: var fd = new FileDrop(); fd.getImages().progress...... Is there a way to just call var fd = new FileDrop. Then do something like fd.progress. Would I just declare the deferred (and return it) in the initialisation of File Drop

Comment: @panthro Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Nm5vK/3/ You can declare the deferred in the constructor if you like.

Comment: Yes like that, but I was more thinking declaring the deferred globally in the class, resolving it in the get images method. I think this would produce the same results as your second fiddle?