# Returning values from a class - not async

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've asked a similar question before regarding deferred, but in my example below, nothing is async so I can return the results straight away. Is deferred still the best method to use?

How would I return a value from this:

```
(function(){
"use strict";

var FileDrop = function() {
    this.init();

};


p.init = function() {

    this._initEvents();
};

p._initEvents = function() {

    $(window).on('drop', this.onDrop.bind(this)).on('dragover', this.onDragOver);
};

p.onDrop = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    return 'something has been dropped!';

};

p.onDragOver = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};


lx.FileDrop = FileDrop;
}(window));
```

I call the above:

```
this.fileDrop = new lx.FileDrop();
console.log(this.fileDrop);
```

Comment: `drag`- and `drop`-events are definitively asynchronous! From what do you want to return what?

Comment: I want to return  - return 'something has been dropped!';

Comment: What exactly is the difference to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034622/returning-data-from-a-class)?

Comment: I just want to know how to return data from a class, e.g. if I declare a class, and the class has methods in it, how can I return data from those methods?

Comment: Yes, you've done that correctly. Calling `this.fileDrop.onDrop()` does return the string you want. Yet, in the invocation from the drop event handler, this return value stays unused.

Comment: How would I get it returned from the drop event handler?

Comment: That's where the deferred comes into play again. You cannot synchronously `return` from an asynchronous handler.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. i'll set up a deferred.